# Can't format text in Alert SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, alert

I would like to modify the font size and color of the text in an Alert in SwiftUI. Adding
modifiers does not seem to work. I must be missing something simple here. I created
the most basic of alert screens, added text modifiers and they are ignored. I created
my own view to show the kind of result I would like. Obviously, since I can make what
I want, I could go that route though it is a lot of work and it just seems like the 
built-in alert ought to be able to do this.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showAlert = false
    @State private var showMyAlert = false
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    Text("Make Some Font Business")
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(.red)

                    Button(action: {
                        self.showAlert.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Toggle System Alert")
                    }

                    Button(action: {
                        self.showMyAlert.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Show MyAlert")
                    }
                }
                if self.showMyAlert {
                    MyAlert(showMyAlert: self.$showMyAlert)
                        .animation(.easeInOut)
                }

            }//vstack

                .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
                .background(self.showMyAlert ? Color.gray.opacity(0.2) : Color.white)

                .alert(isPresented: self.$showAlert) {
                    Alert(title: Text("Important"),
                          message: Text("This text should be large and it should be green")
                            .font(.system(size: 36))
                            .foregroundColor(.green),
                          dismissButton: .default(Text("Ok")))
            }//.alert
        }//geo
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
struct MyAlert: View {  
    @Binding var showMyAlert: Bool  
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .frame(width: 275, height: 180, alignment: .center)
                .foregroundColor(.white).opacity(1.0)
            VStack {
                Text("Important")
                    //.fontWeight(.bold)
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                Divider()
                Text("This text should be large and it should be green")
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                Divider()
                Button(action: {
                    self.showMyAlert.toggle()
                } ) {
                    Text("Ok")
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                }
            }//vstack
            .frame(width: 225, height: 150, alignment: .center)
        }//zstack
    }
}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Xcode 11.3.1 (11C504)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I know modifiers did not work on build-in Alert in SwiftUI. It's a standard system font and size to show on default alert view and not changeable like UIKit default alert. I think the best way is implementing the custom modifier to show the custom alert

Comment: So crazy. SwiftUI gets so much easier, yet the questions still keep coming. Thanks!